# Combine multiIndex dataframes with same columns on first index

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation, multi-index

I have trouble to combine to multi index pandas DataFrames in the way I want. I think an example will be more explicit than a description so here are the two dataframes I have, where X is a random float value :

```
             name    c1    c2
2020-02-10    A       X     X
2020-02-11    A       X     X
2020-02-12    A       X     X
```

and

```
             name    c1    c2
2020-02-10    B       X     X
2020-02-11    B       X     X
2020-02-12    B       X     X
```

And I'd like the result to be :

```
             name    c1    c2
2020-02-10    A       X     X
              B       X     X
2020-02-11    A       X     X
              B       X     X
2020-02-12    A       X     X
              B       X     X
```

My guess is that i should use `pandas.merge` or `pandas.concat` but I can't figure out the correct argument combination for what I want.
At some point I'd like to be able to do it not only with two dataframes but with any number of frames.

Thanks in advance for you help, feel free to ask any other needed details.

**EDIT**: 
The Dataframes are obtained by reading a csv file with pandas.read_csv().

Comment: If you could provide the code to generate those dataframes that would be much easier :)

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()`?

Comment: That was it Quang thank you very much :)

Comment: I will edit the question to add the solution

Comment: Let @QuangHoang, add the answer below so you can accept the answer to close the thread instead. Editing the question makes that the thread remains open.

Comment: Thank for the advice JvdV , it's the first time I post here i'm not really sure of how these things work :) I will let @QuangHoang post his answer.